# CTE with Option Recompile not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

If I do,

```
declare @Q varchar(10) = 'ab1';
SELECT * 
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 't' InnerTable O WHERE O.TId = P.Id)
AND (P.Name_EngLIKE @Per_Name + '%' OR P.PER_NAME_ARB LIKE @Per_Name +'%')
```

Then the query become very slow. If I comment `EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 't' InnerTable O WHERE O.TId = P.Id)` then it will be fast or if I add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` then it will be fast. The problem is that I am using this SQL in CTE(Common Table Expression) which don't allow me to put `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`

**Edit:**
Here is my CTE,

```
WITH CTEPage AS
(
    SELECT  Top(@PageSize * @PageIndex)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM    MyTable(NOLOCK) AS P
    WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 't' FROM OtherTable O WHERE O.PId = P.Id)
            AND (@Name IS NULL OR @Name = '' OR P.NAME_ENG LIKE @Name + '%' OR P.NAME_ARB LIKE @Name + '%')
)

SELECT  TOP(@PageSize) 
        *
FROM    CTEPage AS P

WHERE   P.[RowNumber] > (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize
        ORDER BY P.[RowNumber] ASC;
```

**Update:** The CTE worked. The problem was that @Name was NVarChar while NAME_ENG and NAME_ARB are Varchar

Comment: You need to have option recompile at the end of the whole statement. Did you put it just in the end of the CTE?

Comment: I want to put it in CTE. Putting in the SELECT after CTE make no effect in performance.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the option recompile but how you use the CTE. Maybe a temp. table would be a better solution. Without details like the complete SQL, table & index structure and query plan everything is just guessing.

Comment: At the very least show us the complete expression – showing the CTE – as @JamesZ notes we're just guessing based on your assumption of where the issue is.

Comment: @Richard, I have added my complete SQL

Comment: The first thing I would do is replace all that `ROW_NUMBER` etc. with a order by and [`FETCH NEXT…`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx) clause in the outer most part of the query. *And* then I would start looking at the query plan.

Comment: @Richard, in the bottom SQL I have lot of JOINS. I am only JOINING table for selected page which is not possible with  FETCH NEXT.

Comment: We need to see *full code* (rename anything that is potentially sensitive): make it easy as possible to get an answer.

Comment: @Richard, The INNER JOIN is nothing to do with this. I can remove this, it is not effecting anything

Comment: Using `TOP` on the inner `SELECT`s without `ORDER BY` isn't helping. Are both tables indexed on `Id`? Is `MyTable` indexed on `Name_Eng` and `Name_Arb`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Query Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

> Query hints can be specified only in the top-level query, not in
>   subqueries.

So you cannot use it there. You have to write `query hint` at the end like:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...
)
SELECT ...
FROM cte
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

but as you stated it doesn't help. You can also try changing `EXISTS` with `INNER JOIN` like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable P
JOIN InnerTable O
  ON O.TId = P.Id
WHERE ...;
```

For more possible solutions you should create [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), so we can recreate your problem.

**EDIT:**

If you use SQL Server 2012+ consider using [`OFFSET FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) instead of custom made paging solution like:

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01889/8/0)**

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 5,
        @Page INT = 2;

SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY id
OFFSET @PageSize * (@Page - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: INNER JOIN not effect anything

Comment: @user960567 Please provide http://sqlfiddle.com, without it will be nearly imposible to help. Rename all tables and data so there won't be sensitive data.

Comment: @user960567 Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: The table is massive. I am using 2012

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is "option recompile" but most likely the fact that your SQL is so complex that SQL Server is unable to either estimate the row counts properly, or create correct cost estimation for the selected plan (or the plan creation has a timeout).

To figure out what's going wrong, you should look into actual execution plan and statistics io output and see how many times the code in your CTE is called, are there operators where estimated and actual row counts are off by at least 10x or maybe 100x and if indexes are used properly.

The results from CTE are not cached anywhere by default, and the plan can be such that code gets called hundreds or thousands of times, you could try to run the code in your CTE first and store that result into a temp. table that is indexed properly for joining with the rest of the data.